# How to detect if MSOnline PowerShell module is available - via C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, office365

I'm trying to find out using C# **if MSOnline PowerShell module is available** at OS.

From the first look - nothing difficult. We can invoke PowerShell methods from C#. But for some reason all code snippets I tried to use do not get result with MSOnline module.

For example we use method http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C and pass command like:

Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name (here is the name)

So if we run it for TLS module - it works fine. On the picture below we see how it works in C# console application and on the right - how it looks in PowerShell. Looks fair.

[image]

But everything changes if we try to lookup MSOnline module:

[image]

As we see - C# program gives no results, while PowerShell itself shows us that module is available.

I'm really confused. I thought that is something with my PC, but I have checked on some different ones including Server 2012 R2. Result is the same - this module can not be looked up via C# even if we use exactly the same command as in PS.

Has anyone seen such problem? If yes - what solution can be done to detect via C# if MSOnline PS module is present.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found a solution for my own question:

**You need to make sure that your program and module has both 32 or 64 bits.**

MSOnline is running x64 and if your programm is targeting 32 bit system or has Any CPU and runs 32 bits during runtime - you will get zero result.

That's it.